# Oracle slow query performance with PARALLEL optimization plan

Tags: oracle, performance, query-optimization

I have very simple query

```
SELECT
    A
FROM table
    where B = 'X'
```

explain plan for it looks like

|

```
   0 | SELECT STATEMENT        |                             |     2 |    16 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |        |      |            |

|   1 |  PX COORDINATOR         |                             |       |       |            |          |        |      |            |

|   2 |   PX SEND QC (RANDOM)   | :TQ10000                    |     2 |    16 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,00 | P->S | QC (RAND)  |

|   3 |    PX BLOCK ITERATOR    |                             |     2 |    16 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,00 | PCWC |            |

|*  4 |     INDEX FAST FULL SCAN| TABLE_UNIQUE_ROLES_KEY1     |     2 |    16 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,00 | PCWP |            |
```

It appears to me that Oracle tries to run PARALLEL execution plan.
But I do not have any understanding why it would do it. It significantly slows down query

and if I do

```
SELECT /*+ NO_PARALLEL */
        A
    FROM table
        where B = 'X'
```

it works fast, and plan is:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation            | Name                        | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT     |                             |     2 |    16 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |

|*  1 |  INDEX FAST FULL SCAN| TABLE_UNIQUE_ROLES_KEY1     |     2 |    16 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What causes parallelism in first scenario?

The `degree` on the table is set to 1 but the `degree` on the `TABLE_UNIQUE_ROLES_KEY1` (and the other indexes on the table) are all set to 4.  I don't have privileges to query `v$parameter` so I can't see how parallelism is configured for the database.

`TABLE_UNIQUE_ROLES_KEY1` is a covering index for the query-- it is defined on the columns (`a`, `b`, `c`, `d`) where `a` is the column I'm selecting, `b` is the column that I'm filtering on and `c` and `d` are not involved in the query.

Comment: What parallelism settings do you have at the database level (`show parameter parallel`)?  What is the `degree` from `dba_tables` and `dba_indexes` for the table and the index that the plan is using (or all the indexes on the table)?  Also, what is the definition of `TABLE_UNIQUE_ROLES_KEY1` (what column(s) does it index)?

Comment: table has DEGREE = 1, TABLE_UNIQUE_ROLES_KEY1 has DEGREE = 4 and it indexes 4 columns. Cant run show parameter parallel - it fails. Actually all indexes have DEGREE = 4 and Tables = 1

Comment: Define "it fails"?  Are you getting an Oracle error?  If so, what error?  What tool are you running this in?  If you're using something that doesn't support SQL*Plus commands like `show`, you could query `gv$parameter` instead.  Why are your indexes set to have a degree of 4?  Are you using that elsewhere to encourage parallel query to be used?  Or did some DBA maybe run an unnecessary script to rebuild indexes that inadvertently changed their parallelism settings?  What 4 columns does the index cover (i.e. is it an index on 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' or 'b', 'a', 'c', 'd' or something else)?

Comment: Index is on a, b, c d. In order. I am running Oracle SQL Developer and error is "Show parameters query failed". Unfortunately I do not have right privileges, probably that's why show is failing. I have no idea why indexes set to have a degree of 4. And I do not use anything to encourage parallel query, at least I do not aware of it. But we should not do it. It might DBA did it, but cant tell for sure. Could it be set by default to 4? And would it be a problem?

Answer (score 2):

The immediate cause is that someone has told Oracle that it should use parallel query (the `degree` for your indexes has all been set to 4).  That tends to make the optimizer think that full scanning the index in parallel will be relatively cheap which is why the optimizer is picking that plan.

You can change the parallel setting on your index

```
ALTER INDEX TABLE_UNIQUE_ROLES_KEY1 NOPARALLEL
```

which should stop the optimizer from choosing this plan (you may have to set other indexes to `noparallel` as well to prevent the optimizer from picking a different index to full scan in parallel).  But I'd hesitate to do that until I understood what person or process set the `degree` on your indexes to 4-- if you don't understand the root cause, it's likely that you'll end up either breaking something else or in an endless battle where that person/ process sets your indexes to use parallelism and you set them back.

The two most likely candidates for what caused the indexes to have a `degree` of 4 are that someone (either a developer or a DBA) was trying to get parallel query to kick in for some other query or that the DBA is running an (almost certainly unnecessary) script that periodically rebuilds indexes that does so in parallel without realizing that this changes the `degree` setting on the index and makes it likely that parallel query kicks in.  So you probably need to have a chat with the other developers and/or the other DBAs to figure out whether setting the index to `noparallel` will negatively affect them and whether there are other processes that will be changing the setting on you.

Comment: It feels like very reasonable explanation, Justin. If degree is what causes parallel query to kick in I need to figure out how it gets there. Although on my dev box query runs smooth, no parallel query, although machine is much more less powerful.

Comment: @antohoho - Is degree set to 4 on your local box?  Or 1?  Or default?  It's also possible that the system-level parallelism settings are different.  Since you say you don't have privileges to see those, I'm ignoring those possibilities.

Comment: set to 4, not really my local box, it is a dev box. And I do not experience the same problem as on prod box. I have no privileges

Comment: @antohoho - it is entirely possible that differences in statistics or in settings would lead to different behaviors in different environments.  Setting degree to 4 is a strong push to scan the index in parallel but it's not a guarantee.  Setting the index to noparallel is likely the simplest way to prevent parallel query from being considered.

Comment: Thanks Justin, at least I know in what direction to look. Will try to reach out to our DBA.